# JavaFX: Setting Focus of a TextArea

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple scenario of setting focus of TextArea on the click of a ListView Item. I have tried with the available focus methods like requestFocus() or setFocusTraversable(true/false) but not getting the desired results. 
Here is the event handler code of ListView Item selection.

```
    activeUsersList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        historyTextArea.appendText("ListView Selection Changed (selected: " + newValue.toString() + ")\n");
        messageTextArea.setFocusTraversable(false);
    });
```

**Please let me know if I'm missing something.**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
activeUsersList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        historyTextArea.appendText("ListView Selection Changed (selected: " + newValue.toString() + ")\n");
        Platform.runLater(messageTextArea::requestFocus);
});
```